# How to open a file with the source code editor in MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio for Mac OS X?

Tags: xamarin-studio

In Visual Studio, when I have a file with an extension the IDE doesn't recognize, I can right click on it, and the following menu appears:

[image: VS2010]

If I click on "Open With...", I get the following dialog that lets me choose which editor I want to use to open the file with. It even lets me choose an editor as a default editor.

[image: VS2010 Open With dialog]

On Xamarin Studio for Mac OS X, when I try to do the same thing, I get the following menu instead:

[image: Xamarin Studio]

I want to open this file with the Source Code Editor, just like other files with known extensions. However, this file (.vcg, a CG vertex shader) is not recognized, and I only get the option to open it with the hex editor.

Eventually I cannot open it on the source code editor as I want.

I tried dragging and dropping the file into the editor, but nothing happens. I tried looking for file associations in the Preferences, but nothing even remotely close is available.

I tried setting the default program for that file extension to Xamarin Studio in the OS, but Xamarin Studio still does not believe me that I may want to open this file with the source code editor.

I am using Xamarin Studio 4.2.3 (build 54).

How can I open an arbitrary file like this with the source code editor?

Comment: Xamarin Studio is not yet a full clone of VS. So you'd better report this as a feature request.

Comment: What? The ability to open files?

Comment: Go to Xamarin Bugzilla https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ and fire a new bug on Xamarin Studio with your description above.

Comment: Did you read my question? Did you read my comment to your comment? I want to open a file, which is something that XS already does. Other extensions are opened fine. I just want to know how to force to open a file in the source editor. This is nothing related to new features, and has nothing to do with it being or not a clone of VS.

Comment: I already marked this question to be closed if what you asked is to force the file opened in source editor, as that's not programming related at all, but how to use a tool. I commented simply because if you think the XS behavior is not what you like you can fire a bug. Read the FAQ before posting, http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: According to [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" is on topic. The bug tracking system for most software is meant to report problems with a piece of software, not to ask questions about how to use it.

Comment: "I don't know how to do something, therefore the software is broken and a bug should be filed" is not how I prefer to proceed. I prefer to learn how to use a tool I am not familiar with, before even considering the possibility that the software is broken. But you clearly have a different way of solving your problems.